# How does React Native know my default class name?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React Native. Sorry for asking simple question.

How does React Native know and import my class name and how does it use my class ?
In the snippet my class name is "LotOfGreetings". But how does it know my class name when I import it?

```js
export default class LotOfGreetings extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style = {{alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Greeting name = 'Rexxar'/>
        <Greeting name = 'Jaina'/>
        <Greeting name = 'Valeera'/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is exactly you would like to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find detailed information about export and import. In react-native, export can be performed by two ways as follows:
  1] Exporting without default(i.e. named export):

```
export class TempClass1 {}
```

which has to be imported by using their exact names. This can be done as follows:

```
import {TempClass1 } from './components'
```

2] Exporting with default:

```
export default class TempClass1 {}
```

not essential to import them by using {}. This can be done as follows:

```
import TempClass1 from './components'
```

also not essential to import them by using their exact names. This can be done as follows:

```
import RenamedTempClass1 from './components'
```

You can import both default and named exports at the same time. This can be done as follows:

```
import RenamedTempClass1,{TempClass1} from './components'
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it is the default export, the import name can be anything. For example, with your export code as-is, you could import the component as

```
import SmellyCheese from "./LotOfGreetings"
```

and then you could use your component as `<SmellyCheese/>` because that is how you imported it. So in short, it doesn't know what to call it upon importing it; that is up to you.